# Legend is apears in the wrong place in the page (R): not fully shown

Tags: r, data-visualization, legend

I have added the following command to the plot in R:

```
df<- read.table("filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
tdf=as.data.frame(df[2:ncol(df)])

# draw the plot
bb<- barplot(as.matrix(tdf), beside=T ,
             col=colours,border="black", ylim=c(0,100), ylab="Percentage (%)",xlab="Methods)")

y<-as.matrix(tdf)
text(bb,y+2,labels=as.character(y),pos =1,offset=3,cex = 0.6, col = "black") 



legend("topleft", c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5", "M6"), cex=0.6,inset=c(1,0),xpd=TRUE,  fill=colours)
```

However, the legend appears outside of the plot and not fully shown,

I want it to be seen outside right side of plot. I do not understand the positioning here
[image]

Comment: Please include all of the code you used to generate the plot so that we can reproduce your issue. Probably an issue with par like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568360/legend-disappaers-when-plotting-in-r

Answer (score 0):

If you change in `title` function `"topleft"` to `"topright"` and remove `inset` argument you title should be indicated OK.
Please see the code below:

```
# simulation
set.seed(123)
tdf <- as.data.frame(matrix(rbinom(20, 15, .4) * 8, ncol = 4))

# draw the plot
colours <- 2:6
bb <- barplot(as.matrix(tdf), beside=T ,
             col=colours,border="black", ylim=c(0,100), ylab="Percentage (%)",xlab="Methods)")

y <- as.matrix(tdf)
text(bb,y+2,labels=as.character(y),pos =1,offset=3,cex = 0.6, col = "black") 
legend("topright", c("M1","M2","M3","M4","M5", "M6"), cex=0.6,xpd=TRUE,  fill=colours)
```

Output:
[image: Output]