# Legend not showing in R Plot

Tags: r, plot, legend

I created the following plot but my legend disappeared. It worked earlier but suddenly it won't show...
I already tried restartig the session and rewritting the function but that's not changing anything.

```
USDT_chart = plot(btc_daily_return, lwd= 0.7, col = "darkgrey",type='l', ylab = "Returns", main="Daily returns of Tether")
lines(usdt_daily_return,lty=2,lwd=1,col="red")
lines(eurusd_daily_return, lty = 1, lwd = 0.8, col = "blue")
legend("bottomleft", inset=0.05, legend = c("USDT", "BTC", "EUR/USD"), col = c("red", "darkgrey", "blue"), lty = 1)
```

Does anybody know what might cause this?
Thank you!

Comment: try plotting in a new window with `x11()` sometimes the plot window in r studio is a bit buggy

Comment: We don't have your data, so it's hard to say what's going wrong.  Can you include or generate data that has the same problem, to make your results reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `xpd=TRUE` to legend:
By default, the legend is cut off by the plotting region. This xpd parameter enables plotting outside the plot region. See e.g. ?par for more on xpd.

Learned here: [Legend disappaers when plotting in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44568360/legend-disappaers-when-plotting-in-r)

```
USDT_chart = plot(btc_daily_return, lwd= 0.7, col = "darkgrey",type='l', ylab = "Returns", main="Daily returns of Tether")
lines(usdt_daily_return,lty=2,lwd=1,col="red")
lines(eurusd_daily_return, lty = 1, lwd = 0.8, col = "blue")
legend("bottomleft", inset=0.05, legend = c("USDT", "BTC", "EUR/USD"), 
       col = c("red", "darkgrey", "blue"), lty = 1, xpd=TRUE)
```